# Why was Adon Olam reduced from 16 to 10 verses?

Tags: prayer-book, shabbat-songs

Why did Ashkenazim cut down the original Adon Olam from 16 to 10 verses?  (See original below, by Solomon ibn Gabirol, 11th century Muslim Spain.)  Sephardic siddurim still have all 16 verses, although some have only 14 or 12.  There does not seem to be anything controversial in the additional 6 verses.

[image]

Comment: Different versions of the same poem written at different times?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe those lines are original to the poem? Three of the lines that you marked are not in meter (והוא ראשון והוא אחרון לכל חומר ולכל צורה and the final two verses). The line והוא נסי ומנוסי לי is also not in meter, but the version I am familiar with has ומנוס לי

Comment: How do you know that it was written by ibn Gabirol?

Comment: Scholars say he is the most likely author.